# How to ensure a multivalue field is an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, xpages

I have an issue with a piece of code that is reading a multivalue field that I need to process as if it is an array using a For loop.

```
var iQuestionnaireVar:string; 
var nQuestionnaireVarLen:int;
iQuestionnaireVar = QuestionnaireDoc.getItemValue(iPVar);               
nQuestionnaireVarLen = iQuestionnaireVar.length;
for ( var i = 0; i <= nQuestionnaireVarLen; i++ ) {....}
```

From what I see, it appears that the For loop is actually walking each character of the value instead of each element.

How do I determine if the value in iQuestionnaireVar is empty, a single value or a multivalue.

How do I make this For loop work correctly in each case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [XSnippet "Convert any value to an array"](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=convert-any-value-to-an-array) converts every value to an array.

The result should always work for your for loop.

Comment: Thank you, I found that snippet about five minutes after I posted this question.

Comment: @rrumaner Knut has answered the question quite well, but I figured I'd add the XSnippet I wrote for two reasons: 1- it deals with multi-value fields as *java.util.Vector*s, just as the multi-value field returns with more than one value, and 2- it's a good exercise in understanding return types. If you want an _Array_, what Knut linked is perfect for you.

https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=consistent-ssjs-multi-value-formatting